# Validate phone number using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if phone number is in below format or not

```
+1(111)111-1111
(111)111-1111
1111111111
```

I am using this logic but not getting what I want

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @Customers
VALUES
    ('+1(111)111-1111'),
    ('1111111111'),
    ('11(11)111111'),
    ('11abcd1111'),
    (')123(45678-9-0-'),
    ('(111)111-1111')

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM @Customers
WHERE PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9()-]%'
--AND REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '') LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
AND LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''),'+','')) = 10 -- Alternate test
```

The result I am getting

```
1111111111
11(11)111111
)123(45678-9-0-
```

**UPDATE**:  +1(111)111-1111 should also be in the result list l but it is not. How can I add it?

Comment: You should keep raw data in the database. Formatting is responsibility of the application layer outside of the database

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky thank you. Could you please at least help me with getting a phone number that has +1 in it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server telephone regex check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565888/sql-server-telephone-regex-check)

Comment: Want to clear something if the phone number is like this 2222222222. Are you approving the value? @Rnue

Comment: @ShuRahman yes I am approving this value since it's a 10-digit numeric value.

Comment: okay . Another thing your second format (111)11-1111 have 9 digit is it okay?

Comment: @ShuRahman, it was a mistake. No, if it has only 9 digits then I don't want to add it. I just updated and changed it to 10 digit

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM @Customers
WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE replace('+1(111)111-1111%','1','[0-9]')
   OR PhoneNumber LIKE replace('(111)111-1111%','1','[0-9]')
   OR PhoneNumber LIKE replace('1111111111%','1','[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**My query :**

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @Customers
VALUES
    ('+1(111)11-1111'),
    ('2222222222'),
    ('11(11)111111'),
    ('11'),
    (')123(45678-9-0-'),
    ('(111)111-1111')

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM @Customers
WHERE 
      PhoneNumber  LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
      or PhoneNumber LIKE '[+][0-9][(][0-9][0-9][0-9][)][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
      or PhoneNumber LIKE '[(][0-9][0-9][0-9][)][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

**Output:**

| PhoneNumber |
| --- |
| +1(111)11-1111 |
| 2222222222 |
| (111)111-1111 |

Let me know if you want to replace the **bracket** or **+/-** sign.